# Incorrect path resolving in nrwl workspace with jest

Tags: angular, typescript, path, jestjs, nrwl

I set up jest for an app inside of my nrwl workspace. The component, for instance, I want to test got imports like `@custom/lib`. Now If I'm writing a simple test for this component, I got an error `Cannot find module '@costumLib/data' from 'app.component.ts'`. I check my tsconfig in the root directory and everything is correct. It is working for normal coding. But for writing test, I got this error. But here is the thing, if I'm using relative paths, everything works. So I'm lost. What is causing the error?

Answer (score 2):

Found a **solution**

---

I had to add a `tsconfig.spec.json` into the root directory of the nrwl workspace!

```
{
    "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
    "include": [
      "**/*.spec.ts",
      "**/*.d.ts"
    ]
  }
```